# Cucumber-Serenity - How to execute code before each example of a scenario outline written in Cucumber

Tags: bdd, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to write executable specifications using Serenity and Cucumber.

I would like the stage to be reset before each example of a scenario with examples. Here when serenity runs the second example, the first example is manipulating the outcome of it and in this case it is expecting the list to show `Buy some water` whereas the actual list contains both `Buy some milk` and `Buy some water`

I am writing cucumber specifications in cucumber 4.

`sample.feature`

```
  Scenario Outline: Viewing the items by status
    Given that Jane has a todo list having
    | <task1> | <task2> |
    And she has completed the task called
    | <select> |
    When she filters her list to show only <filter> tasks
    Then her todo list should contain
    | <expected> |


    Examples:
      | task1         | task2        |  select        |filter    | expected |
      | Buy some milk | Walk the dog | Buy some milk  | Active    | Walk the dog  |
      | Buy some water | Walk the cat | Buy some water | Completed |  Buy some water |
```

`SampleStepDefinition.java`

```
  @Before
    public void set_the_stage() {
        OnStage.setTheStage(new OnlineCast());
    }

 @Then("his/her/the todo list should contain")
    public void todo_list_should_contain(List<String> expectedItems) throws Throwable {
        theActorInTheSpotlight().should(seeThat(TheItems.displayed(), equalTo(expectedItems))
                .orComplainWith(MissingTodoItemsException.class, "Missing todos expected:" + expectedItems ));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the Cucumber @Before annotation?

Comment: I have used @Before. I annotated the set_the_stage function with it.

Comment: I'm not used to Serenity, but at a guess I'd say you've got something static in there and it's using the same JVM for each example. Check that `TheItems` is being cleared; that looks like a likely culprit. @Before annotation does get called for each example so the stage is being cleared; it's something else.